# Automatically create a record in another model after using CreateView

Tags: python, django

I have two models (OK 3 models since AssignedAsset is a subclass of Asset), one that tracks assets and another that tracks the history of owners for that asset. When I create a new asset using CreatView I would like to automatically have it create a History record as well.

models.py

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    po = models.ForeignKey('purchaseorders.PurchaseOrder', default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey('locations.Plant')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def save(self):
        forslug = "{0.make}-{0.model}-{0.serial_number}".format(self)
        self.slug = slugify(forslug)
        super(Asset, self).save()

class AssignedAsset(Asset):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

class AssignedHistory(models.Model):
     assset = models.ForeignKey('Asset')
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     date = models.DateField()
     slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.slug

    def save(self):
        forslug = "{0.asset}-{0.date}".format(self)
        self.slug = slugify(forslug)
        super(AssignedHistory, self).save()
```

Here is my view.

```
class NewAssignedAsset(CreateView):
    form_class = AssignedAssetForm
    template_name = 'createassignedasset.html'
    success_url = '/assets'
```

And my forms.py

```
class AssignedAssetForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AssignedAsset
        fields = ['make', 'model', 'serial_number', 'location', 'user', 'po']

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AssignedAssetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #Filter out PO's that have packingslips (otherwise you will quickly have a ridicously big drop-down of every PO in the system)
        self.fields['po'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=PurchaseOrder.objects.filter(packing_slip=''))
```

I thought maybe I could have it create the history when it gets the success URL, so I tried this in my view:

```
import time

def today():
    return time.strftime ("%m/%d/%Y")

class NewAssignedAsset(CreateView):
    form_class = AssignedAssetForm
    template_name = 'createassignedasset.html'
    def get_success_url(self):
        history = AssignedHistory.objects.create(assset=self.object, user=self.object.user, date=today())
        return '/assets'
```

But this throws a TypeError:

save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Anything that would point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it at multiple levels(DB level, form level).

In your case, I'll say you just need to override the `save()` of your `AssignedAssetForm`. (Assuming you set `user` in context of form)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    assigned_asset = super(AssignedAssetForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    user = self.context.get(u'user')
    if user:
        assigned_asset_history = AssignedHistory(asset=assigned_asset, user=user, date=datetime.date.today())
        assigned_asset_history.save()
    return assigned_asset
```

** I am not sure about the context part, you may have to look into how to use `user` in form.

Answer (score 2):

You should write your `Asset.save()` and `AssignedHistory.save()` as:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
   ...
   super(YourModel, self).save(**kwargs)
   ...
```

Note the `**kwargs`. They allow you to accept optional parameters (and a `Model.save()` [has a few](https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/db/models/base.py#L617)).

Comment: It's not enough simply to accept the kwargs, OP should pass them on in the super call.

Comment: @Pynchia, you're right. Expecting a real question to be at the end of the text (and there is a problem to solve there), I've skipped the actual author's intention. Sorry for that.